# How to Pass parameter to an unix shell script to run a job in an unix environment

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to run a .sh script which will basically trigger a  job , i am trying to pass parameter to the .sh file but i am getting error repeteadly .This sh will run a script and execute a batch that will produce some output and will keep in a file.

Below is the folder structure [image]

```
JAVA=$APPSERVER/java/bin
BATCHPROGRAM=com.i21.framework.SystemBootstrap
APPNAME=BATCH_${REGION}
APPDIR=/apps/$APPNAME
#FRAMEWORKDIR=$APPDIR/Framework
BATCHDIR=$APPDIR/DNQLETTER
FRAMEWORKJARLOC=$APPDIR/lib
BATCHJARLOC=$BATCHDIR/lib

FRAMEWORKCONFIG=$APPDIR/config/
BATCHCONFIG=$BATCHDIR/config/

LOG=/logs21C/$APPNAME/DNQLETTER/
DATE_TIME_STAMP=`$DATE +%Y%m%d.log`;
LOGFILE="${LOG}/batch"_"$DATE_TIME_STAMP"

#--------------------------------------------------------------------
# Create the error file and the log file if they do not exist
#--------------------------------------------------------------------
$TOUCH $LOGFILE
$CHMOD 666 $LOGFILE  2>> /dev/null
```

This is the error i am getting

```
./ProcessBatch.sh DEV1 This i am trying using to pass the BATCH Region
```

I am getting below error

```
/bin/touch: cannot touch `/logs21C/BATCH_/DNQLETTER//batch_20170627.log': No such file or directory
./ProcessBatch.sh[80]: /logs21C/BATCH_/DNQLETTER//batch_20170627.log: cannot 
create [No such file or directory]
/bin/ls: /apps/BATCH_/lib/*.jar: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: /apps/BATCH_/DNQLETTER/lib/*.jar: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: /apps/BATCH_/DNQLETTER/config//*.*: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: /apps/BATCH_/config//*.*: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the final slash from the definition of `LOG`, but this is not the reason of the error you are experiencing (it just might cause troubles later on). The reason for the error is:

1. Your error message implies, that the directory `/logs21C/BATCH_/DNQLETTER` does not exist.
2. We can also see that the variable `REGION` is empty.

Comment: Can i pass the region name DEV1 to the script so that it becomes /logs21C/BATCH_DEV1/DNQLETTER ??

Comment: You can supply a parameter either explicitly via the parameter list (as a program argument), or implicitly via an environment variable. It depends on your preference. You can even combine both ways, in that if a parameter is present, it takes it, and if not, it uses an environment variable, and if this is missing, it takes some default value.

Comment: @Mandrek: Actually, in your setup, you already **can** use `REGION` as an environment variable, so if this is enough parameterization for you, you can use this. Just call your script with REGION bound to what you need.

Comment: i am trying ./ProcessBatch.sh DEV1 where i am trying to pass DEV1 as a region variable is this syntax correct ??

Comment: Technically speaking, you pass in this example *DEV1* as the **first parameter** to ProcessBatch.sh. Whether or not this value ends up in the REGION variable, depends on what you actually do with this parameter inside your script.